# SQL concat on unknown fields

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a bit of an odd use-case but suppose a user has provided a SQL query and, without knowing the query, I only have access to the subquery in the form of:

```
SELECT * FROM (users query) subquery
```

Is there any way -- without knowing the fields in the sub-query to do a contains search across all the fields? By this I mean something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (users query) subquery
WHERE CONCAT(all_subquery_fields) like '%term%'
```

Is doing something like `CONCAT(all_subquery_fields)` possible or is this not possible without knowing the fields in the subquery?

Comment: @juergend mysql.

Comment: This is not possible. You would have to parse the query in your program logic and adjust it before executing it.

Comment: You are assuming the user's query has text fields only. Is that true?

Comment: Was wondering if there's a function to convert your result set into a JSON object or XML object. Then querying it could be possible.

Comment: `like '%term%'` is **NOT** a fulltext search. Use the terms correctly.

Comment: @Akina yes, I mean a 'search across all string fields', not the mysql FTS index. What would be a better term for this then?

Comment: @TheImpaler no it could be any type I suppose so all fields would need a `CAST()` to be safe.